# How to write the procedure in Oracle for taking values from 2 tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a few tables on the Oracle server. All of them contain a date_time field in them. the date_time is stored as follows `08-Dec-14 12:55:32`

When given a start and end time, I want all the records from all the tables that lie between this time frame.

The tables do not share anything in common apart from the date_time field.

I have written the following procedure, but not sure if it is correct.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_details (start_time DATE, End_Time DATE) AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.date_time >= start_time and Table1.date_time <= End_Time;
    SELECT FROM Table2
    WHERE Table2.date_time >= start_time and Table2.date_time <= End_Time;
    SELECT FROM Table3
    WHERE Table3.date_time >= start_time and Table3.date_time <= End_Time;
    END;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the result you are expecting ? You can achieve that in different ways depending on what you want.

Comment: Why don't you create a view for this? Why a stored procedure?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak - I want to display all the fields that lie between the start and end times.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I am creating an application that needs to be queried upon. So for the query, I need a procedure as a view will not help with further analysis in my application.

Comment: If you want to _query_ this, then a view **is** the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- Include the columns you are selecting in the `SELECT` clause.
- Do something with the rows you select - either use `INTO` or `BULK COLLECT INTO` to store the values/rows into a collection or use a cursor.

Here is a version that returns a cursor for each `SELECT`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_details (
  start_time IN  DATE,
  End_Time   IN  DATE,
  o_results1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  o_results2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  o_results3 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_results1 FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   Table1
  WHERE  date_time BETEWEEN start_time AND End_Time;

  OPEN o_results2 FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   Table2
  WHERE  date_time BETEWEEN start_time AND End_Time;

  OPEN o_results3 FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   Table3
  WHERE  date_time BETEWEEN start_time AND End_Time;
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
/
```

If you run `SHOW ERRORS;` after compiling a procedure/funcion/package then it will tell you whether it has compiled without errors (or what the error was).

Comment: is there a way I can display from the which table the data is not present. Say, if I do not get any data from table2 between those times, is there a way to display that table2 has no data in that time frame?

Comment: @Vidya - If there is no data from table2 then `o_results2` will contain no rows.

Comment: I have the procedure created. On performing
`EXECUTE  get_details 15-Jul-15 00:00:00 16-Jul-15 00:00:00` I get bind variable 00 not declared. how do I solve this?

Comment: Something like: `VARIABLE o_result1 REFCURSOR; VARIABLE o_result2 REFCURSOR; VARIABLE o_result3 REFCURSOR; EXECUTE get_details( DATE '2015-07-15', DATE '2015-07-16', :o_result1, :o_result2, :o_result3 ); PRINT o_result1; PRINT o_result2; PRINT o_result3;`

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have the start time as **15-Jul-15 08:10:00** and the end time as **15-Jul-15 13:30:00**

Comment: Search for `ORACLE TO_DATE`

Comment: I performed this, got that procedure was successfully completed
`EXECUTE get_details( TO_DATE('15-Jul-15 04:00:10', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('15-Jul-15 20:14:16', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), :o_result1, :o_result2, :o_result3 ); `

But not getting the results on `print o_result1;`